# Reading ASP.NET text box value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a ASP.NET(3.5) page and I have a text box called txtName.

I want to read the value with JavaScript like so but it does not work.

```
var Name = document.getElementById(txtName).value;
alert(Name);
```

Even this does not want to work:

```
var Name = document.FormName.txtName.Value;
alert(Name);
```

This work with plain HTML pages but not with my ASP.NET page, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like `txtName` is the server-side ID of your control. ASP.NET will use a different client-side ID when it renders the control as HTML: probably something like `ctl00_Container_txtName`.

You need to use the control's [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property to get the client-side ID, and then use that in your `getElementById` call:

```
var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID%>').value;
```

Comment: Thanks! How would one check if a check box is selected or not?

Comment: I suppose you'd just use the `.checked` property (a boolean) instead of the `.value` property.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the Jquery.then,juest call:

> $('<%=txtName.ClientID%>').value;